# I created a view of a page and a block, but cannot find either. Where are they?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I created a page view, but when I type in the address for it, it shows "Page not found". When I try to put the block where I want it to go, it doesn't show up, not even under disabled blocks. What step did I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you click on Save button for views?

Comment: voting for this one but also double check the address and flush all caches (menu cache is stubborn!)

Comment: 2Alex, i don't think so, if it doesn't appear even in blocks. Also one of reason: (drupal core or views files) or (db tables) were broken/patched.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you associated an URL with the view, or you are typing the correct URL?
If the URL requires a parameter (e.g., the node ID, the user ID), it is possible you entered a value that is outside the range of the possible values; for example, if the parameter is the node ID, and the higher node ID is 500, when you use 510 for that parameter, you would get a "not found" error message.